# Automation Error - Not enough storage is available to process this command

Tags: c, vb6, createobject

VB6 `CreateObject()` is advising this error message:

> "Automation Error" - "Not enough storage is available to process this command"

The object being created is a DLL written in C.  I'm running the application that's trying to create the object on my machine, and the object itself is being created on my machine also.

I'm running Windows Vista 64bit.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm getting it as well, irregularly.

Comment: I haven't touched VB6 in more than 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

Does the user have security rights to access the directory?  You might try running it via Right-Click "Run As Administrator" as a first step.

Are the references to the dll already in the project or are you creating them on the fly?  Add the direct project ref if possible.

Comment: I tried about 14 different things to resolve this, and it was late.  I'm not sure what exactly resolved it, but this specific error was resolved.  I appreciate it.